# Multithreaded program calculating sum speed-issues

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, pthreads

recently I have writen a programming about Multithreading (calculating sum from 1 to n) and compare the speed of Multithreaded program and normal one.
However, the multithreaded program run much more slower than a program with one loop from 1 to n. So I am really confused why the multithreaded one cant be as fast as I expected. Can someone help me to fix it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
typedef struct data{
    unsigned long long start;
    unsigned long long end;
} data;

void* threadSum( void* p)
{
    data* ptr = (data*)p;

    unsigned long long* thread_sum = (unsigned long long*)calloc(1,sizeof(unsigned long long));
    
    for (unsigned long long i = ptr->start; i<= ptr->end; i++)
    {
        thread_sum[0] += i;
    }
    pthread_exit(thread_sum);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Getinput n
    unsigned long long n, numthread;
    n = atoll(argv[2]);
    numthread = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct timeval start,end;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    //Create threads
    data thread_data[numthread];
    //Declare thread ids;
    pthread_t tid[numthread];
    //Start "numthread" threads and sppace for sum;
    for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < numthread; i++)
    {
        thread_data[i].start = i*n/numthread + 1;
        thread_data[i].end = (i+1)*n/numthread;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, threadSum, &thread_data[i]);
    }

    unsigned long long* sum;
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    for(unsigned long long i=0;i<numthread; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], (void**)&sum);
        result += *sum;
    }
    printf("Result = %llu\n", result);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    double time_taken = end.tv_sec + end.tv_usec/1e6 - start.tv_sec - start.tv_usec/1e6;
    printf("time compipled: %f \n", time_taken);
    return 0;

}
```

I tried to make the multithreaded program run faster than the serial one but I couldnt.

Comment: The job to be solved is most likely too small to pay for the overhead associated with starting and stopping threads.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to make the multithreaded program run faster than the serial one but I couldnt.

1. For small `n`s, the amount of actual computation you are parallelizing is trivial, and is dwarfed by the overhead of thread creation
2. You are using dynamically allocated memory inappropriately and leaking memory

That said, using `gcc -O3 -pthread t.c` I *do* get significant speedup at larger values of `n`, e.g.

```
$ ./a.out 1 1000000000
Result = 500000000500000000
time compipled: 0.336153

$ ./a.out 2 1000000000
Result = 500000000500000000
time compipled: 0.169518

$ ./a.out 4 1000000000
Result = 500000000500000000
time compipled: 0.086015

$ ./a.out 8 1000000000
Result = 500000000500000000
time compipled: 0.045742
```